# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, android, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to connect to postgresql from Heroku (DB is by amazon aws) in Android java

In my host url address is like this

```
postgres://username:password@host:port/database
```

but with jdbc connect I'm using

```
jdbc:postgresql://username:password@host:port/database
```

I'm not sure if that's the problem because I couldn't find any gradle dependency for that

This is my build.gradle
`implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.4.0'`

This is my Java code

```
    private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://username:password@host:port/database";
private Connection connection;
private void connect() {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and when I run the program I get this error

```
W/System.err: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
    W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:236)
    at com.example.myapplication.Database$1.run(Database.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: username:password@host
    W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:208)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    ... 8 more
```

Can anyone help me please to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The url : url = "jdbc:postgresql://username:password@host:port/database" is not correct.
The correct format is:
`jdbc:postgresql://{host}[:{port}]/[{database}]`
You can use:

```
    private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database";
private Connection connection;
private void connect() {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work! same error